# Why is my form.action different than what gets submitted by the form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, get, forms

I am trying to set up a form to transfer data to my php file via forms filled out by the user. I want to create my own GET request so simplify it, but when i submit my form it is a different URL than the one i created.

I console logged my form.action and got (both fabricated data):

.../index.php?search1=987654321&search2=987654321

but the URL i got was (i inputted 987654321):

/index.php?search1=987654321

File: index.html

```
<form id="searchForm" action="/index.php" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="createActionGetRequest()">
    <br><br>
    <text id="search1Text">Social Security Number</text><input id="searchField1" type="text" name="search1"><br>
    <text id="search2Text"></text>
</form>
```

File: helper-functions.js

```
function createActionGetRequest()
{
  var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
  var elements = form.elements;
  var values = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
    values.push(encodeURIComponent(elements[i].name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elements[i].value));
  }

  var userForm = document.getElementById("userType");
  values.push(encodeURIComponent("userType") + '=' + encodeURIComponent(userForm.value));

  var searchForm = document.getElementById("searchType");
  values.push(encodeURIComponent("searchType") + '=' + encodeURIComponent(searchForm.value));

  // dummy test for GET request
  form.action += '?' + "search1=987654321" + '&' + "search2=987654321";
  console.log(form.action);
  alert('pause');
  form.submit();
}
```

Comment: the form submission happens twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a Submit button within a form, its always call `form.submit()` by browser. Which mean 2 calls were made, `/index.php?search1=987654321` made by browser and `/index.php?search1=987654321&search2=987654321` by your js code

You can add `event.preventDefault()` to `createActionGetRequest()` to prevent the browser call.

```
function createActionGetRequest(event)
{
   event.preventDefault()
   ...
}
```

The GET method also replace the request queries with the form input values. You can add another input instead of changing form.action.

```
var input = document.createElement("input"); 
input.type = "text"; 
input.name = "search2"; 
form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: i added the event.preventDefault(); to the top of my function code and i also tried making my search button a button type instead of submit type and im still getting the same error

Comment: Oh the GET method also replace the request queries with the form input values. You can add another input instead of changing form.action.

```
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "text";
 input.name = search2";
 form.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! i did it this way and it worked. if you find a way with out making extra input types let me know!

Answer (score 1):

And some suggestion for your code :

1.Change submit element to button type to prevent fire submit().

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="createActionGetRequest()">
```

2.The values joined from input element should exclude the elements we don't need.

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    if( elements[i].name.startsWith('search')) {
        values.push(encodeURIComponent(elements[i].name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(elements[i].value));
    }
}
```